# How to get selected node checked in kendo treeview ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I want to display selected node checkbox checked in treeview dropdown. How i can achieved this using loop to the treeview data.

So far tried code...

HTML

```
<div kendo-tree-view="legalEntityTree" id="treeViewLegalEnty"
                                            k-data-source="legalEntityDataSource"
                                            options="legalEntityTreeOptions" 
                                            k-rebind="nonPersistentProcess.selectedTypeLegal" ng-click="getCheckedNodes()"></div>
```

treeconfig.js

```
$scope.getCheckedNodes = function(){
        var node;
        var checkedNodes =[];
        var checkedChilds = $scope.legalEntityTree.dataSource.view();
        for (i=0; i <checkedChilds.length; i++ ){
          node = checkedChilds[i];
          if (node.checked){
            checkboxes:true;
          }

        }
        return checkedNodes;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this code to get the selected columns:

```
function getSelectedColumnIDs() {
    var checkedNodes = [];
    tv = $("#tvColumns").data("kendoTreeView");
    checkedNodeIds(tv.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);       
    return checkedNodes;
}

function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].checked) {
            if (nodes[i].id != null && nodes[i].id != "0")
                checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
        }
        if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
            checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
        }
    }
}
```